# Not recieving messages from only one WhatsApp contact

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, motorola-photon

When I first met the love of my life, he insisted that we use WhatsApp to communicate. He lives in Brasil and uses WhatsApp on his Windows Phone. I'm in the United States and use WhatsApp for Android on my Motorola Photon Q.

Over the past few months, our ability to communicate through this app has deteriorated. He says he receives my messages, and that he replies to them, but apparently I don't see them. This is frustrating, to say the least, and puts a lot of unneeded stress on both of us. I've worried myself sick over it.

He says that I'm the only one this happens to, and that communication with his Brazilian contacts works just fine. One of my friends in the Philippines just got WhatsApp for Android and I can communicate with him perfectly.

I'm really clueless. I've scoured the Internet for answers, but I can't seem to find any. I can send messages, and in the rare time that I do receive the messages from my boyfriend, it is late at night. I never receive any during the day. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the app countless times, and my WiFi connection at my house is perfect. But this seems to only be getting worse. He says he sends me several messages a day, but I only get some of the messages about every other day--usually every two days.

I'm not a tech by any means, but it seems like there might be something wrong with the different versions of WhatsApp. Android communicating with the Windows Phone. So if this is the case, then my question here is unneeded. I've contacted WhatsApp Inc. with my concerns and have yet to receive a reply.

This sucks, to say the least.

UPDATE: I have contacted one of my boyfriend's friends in Brasil. I can communicate with them perfectly. They said y boyfriend said there was an issue with his phone. But I'm not sure that's the case. I uninstalled WhatsApp and downloaded it through WhatsApp's website. I can now see when my boyfriend is online and when he types. But I do not receive the messages he sends.

Comment: Have you tried sending a message to someone else who lives in Brazil?

Comment: Why not try any one of the other 100s of the similar app? I know this is not the solution to your problem but why are you stressing over something irrevelant?

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand if the problem is of your phone or of something else, ask your boyfriend if he sees a double-check or just one check (✓) near the messages he sent you, but you didn't receive.

- **If there are two checks**, the message was delivered to your phone, but for some reasons it isn't shown up. Maybe because of a malicious application?
- **If there is just one check**, the problem is on the side of whatsapp as messages are sent to their servers but not delivered to you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem just two days ago. I could not receive messages from my husband's whatspp phone. The message had been sent by him, but it was not delivered to me. (i.e. it shows only one tick).

I then uninstalled whatspp from my phone and reinstalled it. Now it works again :-)

The problem with my whatspp was that, I have clean master installed in my phone. It recognized some important files of whatsapp as junk and removed it. So whatspp couldn't function properly until it was reinstalled.

Answer (score -1):

Create a group with only you and the other contact in it, then chat there. I had the same problem and that was how I solved it.